# The definition of Hilbert space $H^k_0(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Some time I see the $H^k_0(\Omega)$ space is the completion of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ in $\|\cdot\|_{H^k}$ norm. But when we solve pde, we use $H^k_0(\Omega)=\left\{u\in{}H^k(\Omega):u^{(\alpha)}\vert_{\partial{\Omega}}=0 \quad\forall\vert\alpha\vert<k\right\}$, where $u^{(\alpha)}$ indicates the $\vert\alpha\vert$th weak derivative in the normal direction of the trace. How could I show the equivalence of those two definitions?

Comment: It is obvious that the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ contains $H^k_0(A)$ for $A$ open $\subset \Omega$. Then, multiply $u$ with a $C^\infty_c$ approximation of $1_\Omega$ and show it approximates $u$ in the $H^k$ norm only if for $|\alpha| < k$ : $\partial_\alpha u |_{\partial \Omega} = 0$